# How to efficiently construct HTML on-the-fly in PHP

Tags: arrays, string

Four approaches occur immediately to me:

a) Simply echo many small fragments;
b) Create logically complete blocks by concatenating literals and PHP variables, then echo the block;
c) Start with a string representing a logically complete block with place-holder tokens, replace the tokens with PHP variables, the echo the block;
d) Create an array of strings comprising the literal fragments of the block, interspersed with named place-holder elements, then traverse the array and replace the placeholders, then join the array and echo the result.

(a) sounds intuitively inefficient, but since the system will probably buffer them, it may be OK, and then there are no string concatenation or substitution operations. However, the code will look awful and probably be difficult to maintain.

(b) is very messy, and since HTML contains lots of quote characters, it's tedious to get the syntax right - you often can't just use double quotes with interspersed variables. Also I suspect that string concatenation is inefficient.

(c) is good from a maintainability point of view, since you can clearly see the intended HTML, but substitution is probably also inefficient.

(d) may be quite efficient, since the join function can be clever and just allocate memory for the combined string once, and then copy the parts into it. It is also reasonably maintainable if the starting array literal is nicely laid out.

I'm sure lots of developers have thought about this, and quite likely I have missed some obvious alternative - which is the way to go?

Comment: I forgot HEREDOC - better than just (c) ;=(

Answer (score 0):

It's a mix of a) and b), depending on what you need, but you shouldn't be doing this yourself, people have already made things like this for you to use for free, pick up a Framework. They take a little while to learn, but once you get into it it's so much faster and maintainable.

I'd say take a look at Zend since it's what i know ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_framework ).

Comment: What if I were writing a framework ;=) Not an answer to my question!